# Port forwarding to local ip is not working in windows server 2019

Tags: port-forwarding, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2019

I want to run Call Of Duty 4 host server.

First I install the windows server 2019 in Google cloud platform. 
After that I install the call of duty game server and run it is running on local ip `10.128.0.4:28960`
You can join game to this local ip address inside the server everything work perfect but I want to expose it for other world.

My server ip address is `34.67.221.157`

I follow these steps to forward port to local ip [Port Forward in windows server](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/)

1. I make the ip address static `10.128.0.4`
2. Port forward using this command
   `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=10.128.0.4 listenport=28960 connectaddress=34.67.221.157 connectport=28960` __> command run successfully
3. After that I add this port into firewall
   `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”forwarded_CODport_28960” protocol=TCP dir=in localip=10.128.0.4  localport=28960 action=allow` __> command run successfully

After that I try to connect `34.67.221.157:28960` from my game but it's not also to connect

> Server connection timeout

Here is what it show after all these successful commands [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA1Hu.jpg)

I'm new in windows server what step I miss please let me know

**Update: Open Port in GCP Firewall**

1. I remove the port forwarding role
2. Disable the firewall in VM
3. Add port `28960` in GCP firewall [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHAhl.jpg)
4. After that I check the open port in [nmap.online results](https://nmap.online/result/b2db86b931715c67f561d951eb4073c8bb3eb7f3/34672211571)

> Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-09 08:29 PDT
>   Nmap scan report for 157.221.67.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.67.221.157)
>   Host is up (0.034s latency).
>   PORT    STATE    SERVICE      VERSION
>   21/tcp  filtered ftp
>   22/tcp  closed   ssh
>   25/tcp  filtered smtp
>   80/tcp  closed   http
>   110/tcp filtered pop3
>   143/tcp filtered imap
>   443/tcp closed   https
>   445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
>   Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at   >https://nmap.org/submit/ .
>   Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.80 seconds

[For Better result view](https://nmap.online/result/b2db86b931715c67f561d951eb4073c8bb3eb7f3/34672211571)

Comment: Hello @Azeem and welcome on ServerFault. Questions here should be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. I've voted to move your question to SuperUser sister site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You do not need to create any forwarding rules** between internal and external IPs. Also, you don't really need to reserve an internal IP for external connections.

Meanwhile, you can [reserve an external static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) to have the same external IP for external connections.

**To solve this issue** you should follow steps below:

1. remove port forwarding rules you've created in your Windows VM
2. create a firewall rule to allow connections to port 28960 on your Windows Firewall (or just disable it temporary - your VM will be protected by GCP Firewall)
3. [create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow connections to port 28960 on GCP Firewall from your IP or from any IP (`0.0.0.0/0`)
4. check current open ports with [Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) (like `nmap -p 28960 EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM`) or with other tool
5. connect to `EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM:28960` from your game (from premises)

**UPDATE**:

As I can see port 28960 is closed:

```
$ nmap -p 28960 34.67.221.157
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-09 18:40 CEST
Nmap scan report for 157.221.67.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.67.221.157)
Host is up (0.20s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
28960/tcp closed unknown
```

It could be because Windows Firewall still engaged, please follow steps below:

1. open an administrative command prompt and run command:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
   ```

   or open PowerShell and run command:

   ```
   Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False
   ```
2. go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click `EDIT` -> go to `Network Tags` -> [add network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) like `game-server` -> click `Save`
3. create temporary firewall rule:

   ```
   gcloud compute firewall-rules create game-server --direction=INGRESS --priority=999 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp,udp --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=game-server
   ```
4. check again open ports with commands `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM` and `nmap -p 28960 EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM`

In addition, **have a look at this [article](https://support.activision.com/articles/ports-used-for-call-of-duty-games) to check if you need to open more ports** and then you should check them with command `nmap -p PORT EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM`.

Comment: I follow these steps but it's not working for me checkout question update

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks port is open now. I just figured out that this was udp port